# SQL Big Query - How to write a COUNTIF statement applied to an INTERVAL column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting

I have a trip_duration column in interval format. I want to remove all observations less than 90 seconds and count how many observations match this condition.

My current SQL query is

```
WITH 
org_table AS (
    SELECT
    ended_at - started_at as trip_duration
    FROM `cyclistic-328701.12_month_user_data_cyclistic.20*`
)
SELECT
  COUNTIF(x < 1:30) AS false_start
FROM trip_duration AS x;
```

I returns *Syntax error: Expected ")" but got ":" at [8:16]*

I have also tried

```
SELECT
  COUNTIF(x < "0-0 0 0:1:30") AS false_start
FROM trip_duration AS x
```

It returns *Table name "trip_duration" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.*

I've read through other questions and have not been able to write a solution.
My first thought is to cast the trip_duration from INTERVAL to TIME format so COUNT IF statements can reference a TIME formatted column instead of INTERVAl.

~ Marcus

Comment: where you got `trip_duration`? shouldn't it be `org_table`?

Comment: When I change it to  `FROM org_table AS x`  it returns *No matching signature for operator < for argument types: STRUCT<trip_duration INTERVAL>, STRING. Supported signature: ANY < ANY at [8:1*  I understand this as I should change the operator but I'm unsure how I could do that.

Comment: anyway - see my answer below. hope it will help you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To filter the data without the durations less than 90 secs:

```
SELECT
  * # here is whatever field(s) you want to return
FROM
  `cyclistic-328701.12_month_user_data_cyclistic.20*`
WHERE
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, SECOND) > 90
```

You can read about the **TIMESTAMP_DIFF** function [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_diff).

To count the number of occurrences:

```
SELECT   
  COUNTIF(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at,SECOND) < 90) AS false_start,
  COUNTIF(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at,SECOND) >= 90) AS non_false_start
FROM
  `cyclistic-328701.12_month_user_data_cyclistic.20*`
```

Answer (score 1):

Below example shows you the way to handle intervals

```
with trip_duration  as (
  select interval 120 second as x union all
  select interval 10 second union all 
  select interval 2 minute union all 
  select interval 50 second
)
select 
  count(*) as all_starts,
  countif(x < interval 90 second) as false_starts
from trip_duration
```

with output

[image]